# name is not defined - nome/variavel não definida, tkinter e slite3 help

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

estou começando a estudar `sqlite3` na marra, e esta sendo difícil, mas já consegui algumas coisa, o problema é que na hora de compilar o programa aparece o seguinte erro:

```
"name 'adic' is not defined".
```

Segue o código:

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3

class Principal:
    def __init__(self):
        janela_principal = Tk()
        janela_principal.geometry("400x400+50+50")
        #janela_principal.overrideredirect(True)

        lb0 = Label(janela_principal)
        lb0.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=13)


        lb1 = Label(janela_principal, text="Digite um número:")
        lb1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)
        digite_numero = Entry(janela_principal, width=35)
        digite_numero.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)
        separador = Frame(janela_principal, height=2, bd=3, relief=SUNKEN, width=340)
        separador.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)

        lb2 = Label(janela_principal, text="Assunto:")
        lb2.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)
        digite_assunto = Entry(janela_principal, width=35)
        digite_assunto.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

        separador = Frame(janela_principal, height=2, bd=3, relief=SUNKEN, width=340)
        separador.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

        add = Button(janela_principal, text="ADICIONAR NOME", relief=SOLID, border=1, foreground="BLUE", command=adic)
        add.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        apagar = Button(janela_principal, text="APAGAR NOME", relief=SOLID, border=1, foreground="RED", command=apag)
        apagar.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=E)


        lb3 = Label(janela_principal)
        lb3.grid(row=6, column=0)


        rolagem = Scrollbar(janela_principal)
        rolagem.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky=N+S+E)

        caixa_exibição = Listbox(janela_principal, relief=SOLID, border=1, width=45, height=15, font=("Gentium Basic", 11))
        caixa_exibição.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)


        #for i in range(100):
        #    caixa_exibição.insert(END, i)

        # attach listbox to scrollbar
        caixa_exibição.config(yscrollcommand=rolagem.set)
        rolagem.config(command=caixa_exibição.yview)



        #Banco
        conectar = sqlite3.connect("numeros.db")
        cursor = conectar.cursor()
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nomes(numeros TEXT, assunto TEXT)")
        conectar.commit()
        lista = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM nomes")
        for i in lista:
            caixa_exibição.insert(END, i)

    def adic():
        numerosx = digite_numero.get()
        assuntox = digite_assunto.get()
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO nomes values(?, ?)", (numerosx, assuntox))
        conectar.commit()
        caixa_exibição.insert(END, numerosx)
        caixa_exibição.insert(END, assuntox)

    def apag():
        numerosy = str(caixa_exibição.get(ACTIVE))[3:-3]
        assuntoy = str(caixa_exibição.get(ACTIVE))[3:-3]

        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM nomes WHERE name=?, ?", (numerosy, assuntoy))
        conectar.commit()
        caixa_exibição.delete(ANCHOR)





        janela_principal.mainloop()

Principal()
```

Comment: como assim? Você pode me dar um exemplo?

Comment: Seu código está bastante confuso: as funções `adic` e `apag` estão indentada, como se fossem métodos da classe `Principal`, mas foram definidas como funções, sem o parâmetro `self`. Elas deveriam ser métodos da instância, métodos da classe ou funções fora da classe? Além disso, dentro da função `adic` você utiliza o objeto `digite_numero` que foi definido em `__init__` e, portanto, não existe dentro desta função. Este objeto deveria ser um campo de instância? Perceba que isso nem tem relação com o SQLite ainda.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Por indicações de profissionais, indico sempre definir os métodos antes do resto do programa (**embora não seja necessário, faça como quiser**).

Por estar utilizando classes, é necessário utilizar self. para poder acessar as variáveis dentro da classe, por esse motivo "adic" aparecia como "não definido", pois estava fora de seu escopo.

Segue o código mostrando algumas aplicações nesse sentido, não é necessariamente obrigatório utilizar tudo como utilizei:

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3

class Principal:
    def adic(self): #Métodos antes, com o paramentro self para receber variáveis do __init__
        numerosx = self.digite_numero.get() #Por ser uma variável utilizada apenas dentro dessa função, não existe a necessidade do self.
        assuntox = self.digite_assunto.get()
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO nomes values(?, ?)", (numerosx, assuntox)) #Cursor é uma variável do método __init__, por esse motivo, precisamos utilizar self. para acessá-la
        self.conectar.commit()
        self.caixa_exibição.insert(END, numerosx+" "+assuntox) #Aqui você irá inserir: 'numerox assuntox', do modo como estava fazendo, você inseria um por vez, fazendo com que um ficasse abaixo do outro
        #self.caixa_exibição.insert(END, assuntox)

    def apag(self):
        selecionada = str(self.caixa_exibição.get(ACTIVE)).replace('(','').replace(')','').replace("'","").split(',') #Coleta a linha selecionada, e por ser uma string, eu faço o tratamento da linha, removendo varias coisas como "(')". Além disso, estou fazendo um array, separando os elementos por ",".
        try:
            self.numerosy = selecionada[0]
            self.assuntoy = selecionada[1][1:]
        except:
            selecionada = str(self.caixa_exibição.get(ACTIVE)).split(" ")
            self.numerosy = selecionada[0]
            self.assuntoy = selecionada[1]

        self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM nomes WHERE numeros='"+self.numerosy+"' AND assunto = '"+self.assuntoy+"'") #Corrigi a Query
        self.conectar.commit()
        self.caixa_exibição.delete(ANCHOR)
    def __init__(self):
        janela_principal = Tk()
        janela_principal.geometry("400x400+50+50")
        #janela_principal.overrideredirect(True)

        lb0 = Label(janela_principal)
        lb0.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=13)


        lb1 = Label(janela_principal, text="Digite um número:")
        lb1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)
        self.digite_numero = Entry(janela_principal, width=35)
        self.digite_numero.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)
        separador = Frame(janela_principal, height=2, bd=3, relief=SUNKEN, width=340)
        separador.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2)

        lb2 = Label(janela_principal, text="Assunto:")
        lb2.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)
        self.digite_assunto = Entry(janela_principal, width=35) #Usar self. para tornar a variável acessível
        self.digite_assunto.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

        separador = Frame(janela_principal, height=2, bd=3, relief=SUNKEN, width=340)
        separador.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)

        add = Button(janela_principal, text="ADICIONAR NOME", relief=SOLID, border=1, foreground="BLUE", command=self.adic)
        add.grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
        apagar = Button(janela_principal, text="APAGAR NOME", relief=SOLID, border=1, foreground="RED", command=self.apag)
        apagar.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=E)


        lb3 = Label(janela_principal)
        lb3.grid(row=6, column=0)


        rolagem = Scrollbar(janela_principal)
        rolagem.grid(row=7, column=2, sticky=N+S+E)

        self.caixa_exibição = Listbox(janela_principal, relief=SOLID, border=1, width=45, height=15, font=("Gentium Basic", 11))
        self.caixa_exibição.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=W)


        #for i in range(100):
        #    caixa_exibição.insert(END, i)

        # attach listbox to scrollbar
        self.caixa_exibição.config(yscrollcommand=rolagem.set)
        rolagem.config(command=self.caixa_exibição.yview)



        #Banco
        self.conectar = sqlite3.connect("numeros.db")
        self.cursor = self.conectar.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nomes(numeros TEXT, assunto TEXT)")
        self.conectar.commit()
        self.lista = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM nomes")
        for i in self.lista:
            self.caixa_exibição.insert(END, i)


        janela_principal.mainloop()

Principal()
```

Comment: Um detalhe: a ordem que é definido os métodos não importa, então não fará diferença definir `adic` antes de `__init__`.

Comment: eu ficaria mais confortável, se você não conhece bem a linguagem, que testasse o que fez, antes de responder com um código de mais de 30, 40 linhas feito no chute.

Comment: "Por indicações de profissionais, indico sempre definir os métodos antes do resto do programa " aqui você tem um outro profissional **não indicando** isso. Em Python, a recomendação é definir o `__init__` antes dos outros métodos.

Comment: @NathanSchroeder Cara muito obrigado, eu consegui concluir meu projeto. Daqui a um tempo vou fazer um projeto maior, espero que na próxima se eu ficar com alguma dúvida você possa me ajudar de novo. :D, Thank You Man

Comment: @NathanSchroeder desculpa ser chato, mas preciso de um detalhe. É porque vou fazer algo maior depois, então preciso saber pelo menos a base, vamos lá. Quando adicionamos o item na linha e excluir está tudo ok, do jeito que eu queria, só que depois que o item é salvo, e o programa é executado pela segunda vez a coluna 1 e 2 vem com chaves, por exemplo: 
'{ 1819 - P1/2018} {Informação}', respectivamente colunas 1 e 2, ambas com { }, como faço para consertar isso?

Comment: @VictorS' Se você inserir '1' e 'teste' isso não acontece, se você apenas apertar adicionar, com os campos vazios, isso acontece, creio que sejam caracteres em que o DB não leia corretamente, creio que você deva dar uma pesquisada sobre isso.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigado @NathanSchroeder

Answer (score 4):

Nesse caso é bem simples: você está fazendo uma classe, não com funções soltas - então ao declarar o `command=...`, em vez de `command=adic`, você deve usar `command=self.adic`.

E, claro, já que são métodos, coloque o parâemtro `self` na definição delas.

Se quiser usar só como função, tudo bem - nesse caso é só retira-las do corpo da classe (identando-as na coluna zero), aí não precisa do `self.adic` nem do parâmetro `self`, mas aí você também não tem como compartilhar variáveis entre as suas funções.

A vantagem de fazer tudo como classe (sem herdar de nenhuma classe do tkinter, exatamente como está no seu código), é que você pode definir  variáveis no `__init__`  que serão atributos da classe - então, a sua função `adic` precisa acessar a `caixa_exibicao` por exemplo - ela pode fazer isso, se  **tanto no `__init__` quanto no método você sempre usar `self.caixa_exibicao`**. Acrescente  o `self.` em todas as variáveis que precisar acessar de todas as funções do seu código.

(o `self.` vale para o `cursor` e todas as outras variáveis que você compartilha, claro).

Comment: jsbueno Meu Muito obrigado pelo excelente explicação, desejo sucesso na sua carreira, valeu.